# Customer Chat Plugin does not trigger Get Started Button Postback

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

We are running a chatbot based on the Facebook Messenger Platform. To introduce the bot to new users we have enabled the get started button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/welcome-screen#set_postback

Everything works fine from within the messenger. After starting a conversation our application receives a `messaging_postbacks` event. Trying the same from the customer chat plugin triggers nothing at all. According to the documentation this should work though: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin#steps

> If a new conversation is started via the plugin, and your bot has set
>   up the get started button, we will send a messaging_postbacks webhook
>   event to your webhook when the user clicks the get started button.

Do we miss something? Is there something else we have to do? Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you only test it in that sequence, with the same user? (If the user has seen the greeting message _once_, it will not be shown again AFAIK.) Do you see the actual button in both cases?

Comment: Yes. We always delete the old conversation before testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any postback, you can check if you white-listed your domain where your customer chat plugin is added. 
Also, you can use `messaging_referrals` for old users.